# Render collection with block, instead partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to use a block, instead of separate partial file when rendering collection of items? Like this:

```
<%= render @posts, cached: true do |post| %>
  <%= some_usefull_helper_method post.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The goal is not to create separate partial file just for single line of code (in this example this line calls helper method). And at the same time, use rails collection caching feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using `render` and passing an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object because that way Rails infers you're trying to render a partial `posts/post`, from the application of `to_partial_path` in `@posts`.

You can instead use `<%= %>` which will print whatever you're passing, invoking your helper and handling the HTML generation and caching by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache a portion of a page like this

```rb
<% cache @posts do %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= some_helper_method post.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or like this even which will cache each post separately, the previous example caches the collection.

```rb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% cache post do %>
    <%= some_helper_method post.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

[Link to a useful article](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/04/03/russian-doll-caching-in-rails.html)